# Get changes from non accepted pull request from someones repo

Tags: github

Is it possible to get changes from pull request of somebones repo. I've tried to contact with owner of this repo, but he is inactive from last year.

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub, all pull requests are accessible as special refs named `refs/pull/<num>/head`.

So let's say you have a local clone of https://github.com/jonas/tig and want to merge PR #903:

```
git checkout -b temporarybranch master

git pull  https://github.com/jonas/tig  refs/pull/903/head
```

---

The pull request page also shows where it was made from. For example, if I'm viewing the same PR on the website, it says below the header:

> wants to merge 1 commit into `jonas:master` from `ffes:editorconfig`

that means the changes were in branch "editorconfig" from "ffes/tig" and you can get them like this:

```
git checkout -b temporarybranch master

git pull  https://github.com/ffes/tig  editorconfig
```